# make assets get permission denied for webpack in Prestashop 8.1

Tags: node.js, webpack, permissions, prestashop

I cloned **Prestahop** development from git, checked out `8.1.x` branch, added `symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` using composer, run the installer from browser, then tried to run `make assets` from the root folder of the project and I got this (tried setting ownership to my user `k`, to `k:www-data` and tried running `make assets` with `sudo su`):

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/var/www/html/prestashop_dev/admin-dev/themes/new-theme/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/.config/fork-ts-checkerrc'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:586:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:454:35)
    at readFileSync (/var/www/html/prestashop_dev/admin-dev/themes/new-theme/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/readFile.js:45:33)
    at ExplorerSync.loadSearchPlaceSync (/var/www/html/prestashop_dev/admin-dev/themes/new-theme/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:69:48)
    at ExplorerSync.searchDirectorySync (/var/www/html/prestashop_dev/admin-dev/themes/new-theme/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:55:32)
    at run (/var/www/html/prestashop_dev/admin-dev/themes/new-theme/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:35:27)
    at cacheWrapperSync (/var/www/html/prestashop_dev/admin-dev/themes/new-theme/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/cacheWrapper.js:28:18)
    at ExplorerSync.searchFromDirectorySync (/var/www/html/prestashop_dev/admin-dev/themes/new-theme/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:47:49)
    at run (/var/www/html/prestashop_dev/admin-dev/themes/new-theme/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:39:21)
    at cacheWrapperSync (/var/www/html/prestashop_dev/admin-dev/themes/new-theme/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/cacheWrapper.js:28:18) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/.config/fork-ts-checkerrc'
}
make: *** [Makefile:8: assets] Error 2
```

I suspect that the problem is the leading slash in `/.config/fork-ts-checkerrc`, but I'm new to node and webpack and can't find that file anywhere.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!